# ARKIT: How to move object in mid air like GiPHY World app

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I have implemented methods to move an object that is on top of a surface by using UIPanGesture, and utilizing the technique of raycasting against the plane.. to locate the new coordinate for the object as you drag.

But what if the object is in mid air, you cannot raycast agaisnt any plane. I noticed that GIPHY World app, allows you to switch between 2 modes:

1. Plane detection (where objects are allowed to be placed ONLY on a
   surface)
2. Free mode (where objects can ONLY be placed floating in front of the camera)

When you have the object floating, the user is able to drag on screen in any direction and the object will follow correctly, even if you physically move. I notice that you dont have to touch the object to move it, but as long as you drag in the screen.

I wonder if you guys can propose some code to convert the 2D screen drag to how the 3d object moves. Ex.

- If you are in front of the object, dragging on the screen UP/DOWN
  will    move the object in Z coordinate... close or far away.
- But if you physically move to a side.. and again drag on the screen UP/DOWN the object now translates over the X coordinate. <---    how
  do they do that ?

Here a video of how it works. 
https://youtu.be/16iMMuwjfIc

Here you can see what I've tried based in @Vollan's answer below. You can see how repositioning doesnt work like GiPHY APP.
https://youtu.be/ZoWj6WRBY58

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all i will go over moving the object after you moved physically.

When you place nodes in the reality you can choose wether you want to make it from the camera perspective or if you actually want to put it in the world position.

1: World position will place the origin of the Z,X,Y axises at where the camera was when you started the AR session.
2: Camera position means that the origin will follow you around and be bound to the camera. This will cause the Node to always be 3D.

Now if you choose world position and you choose to walk around the node or the start up position for example 90 degrees. Then you will have another angle on the origin of the axis's as the Z and X axis will have changed places. Causing UP / DOWN in Z to be converted into X.

Secondly i use this code:

```
@objc func adjustWindow(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    var startPosition: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    // Fetch location for touch in sceneView
    let location: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: sceneView)

    // Fetch targets at the current location
    let hits = self.sceneView.hitTest(location, options: nil)

    // Check if it's a node and it's a window node that has been touched
    guard let node = hits.first?.node, node.name == "name" else {return}

    // Make sure user is using 1 finger to move the view
    if gesture.numberOfTouches == 1 {
        switch gesture.state {
        case .failed, .cancelled, .ended:
            // Reset position after finished
            startPosition = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            break
        case .began:
            // Save start position, so that we can check how far the user have moved
            startPosition = location
        case .changed:
            // Fetch new x and y position
            let deltaX = Float(location.x - startPosition.x)/20
            let deltaY = Float(location.y - startPosition.y)/20

            // Transform and apply the new location
            let box = node.transform
            let translation = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(deltaX, deltaY, 1)
            let newTrans = SCNMatrix4Mult(box, translation)
            node.transform = newTrans

            node.localTranslate(by: SCNVector3Make(deltaX, deltaY, 1))
            // Set new location
            startPosition = location
        default:
            break
        }
        // Make sure user is using 2 fingers for scaling the view
    }
 }
```

This is the first version i wrote of this scenario and how it moves will probably only work in my application as i rotated/tilted my object in the .DAE file a bit wrong. But you might the idea behind fetching your touch location and track the changes for it.

Implementing
 `ARSessionDelegate` and

```
 var matrix: matrix_float4x4!

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        // Fetch and store current camera position
        matrix = frame.camera.transform
    }
```

Will get you the current camera position at all times as it's updating when you move your camera. I have not yet figured out how to apply this. Maybe by using:

`let translation = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(deltaX*matrix.m41, deltaY*matrix.m42, 1*matrix.m43)`

Or something.

Good luck.

Comment: mmmm In your first paragraph I think you got what I meant. But the way you implemented the node relocation doesnt take in account the fact that you physically move around the floating object (also I dont know if the 2 finger touch section is related). And.. are you moving ALL the objects in the scene ? 
Sorry I implemented the first 1 finger touch section and it didnt do what I expected :( :(

Comment: Yes in that function i was moving all the objects in the scene, and sorry for the 2 fingered one. I have updated the code now to be somewhat better. Can you explain what happen? It moves the X and Y axis for me as i drag, and if i move around the object it's getting messed up

Comment: I actually wanted it to move Over X,Z not X,Y. I just refactored. And yes it works. But as you mentioned... if I change the angle in which Im looking at the object.. then axises are inverted.. or more like.. stay consistent. Let me make a video to show you.

Comment: Don't worry about the video, i get what you mean, sadly i have not been able to fix that myself. So can't help you on that point :(

Comment: Edit my answer at the bottom. At least something to work from :)

Comment: @omarojo i found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237805/how-to-move-a-rotated-scnnode-in-scenekit